# Mixed greeks in Python - How plot the following

Tags: black-scholes, programming, greeks

I am interested about greeks with Black-Scholes. In this case, I have the python formula to compute the greek called "Vanna", that is: $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial \sigma \partial S}$ the sensitivity of option value P with respect to a joint movement in underlying and volatility.

Now, let's consider the following example, with S = [100,120] a list of 50 equispaced points and $\sigma$ = [0.05,0.7] another list of 50 equispaced points, in the code below I am able to generate the plot of this greek, with respect each element of S and $\sigma$, i.e. with respect the first element of S and first element of $\sigma$ list, after that with respect to the second element of both list, till the last element of both list.

My question is: **How can I take all the possible combinations, between these 2 lists? Maybe it can be done with a 3-dimensional plot? How can I do this in Python?**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
underlying = np.linspace(100,120,50)
K = 100
T = 1
r = 0
sigma = np.linspace(0.05,0.7,50)
def Vanna_(S, K, T, r, sigma):
    lista = []
    d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 1/2 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1-vol*T**(1/2)
    return (1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * S  * np.exp(-d1 ** 2 * 1/2) * np.sqrt(T))/S * (1- d1/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)))
plt.plot(Vanna_(underlying, K, T, r, sigma))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from itertools import product

S = np.linspace(100,120)
vols = np.linspace(0.05,0.7)
combs = list(product(S, vols))

values = [Vanna_(underlying, K, T, r, sigma) for underlying, sigma in combs]
x, y = np.hsplit(np.array(combs), 2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.scatter3D(x, y, values, c=values);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution using `Plotly`.

**First of all** let me correct a typo in your code

```
def Vanna_(S, K, T, r, sigma):
    lista = []
    d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 1/2 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1-sigma*T**(1/2)
    return (1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * S  * np.exp(-d1 ** 2 * 1/2) * np.sqrt(T))/S * (1- d1/(sigma*np.sqrt(T)))
```

Then **let me use pandas to format the result**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

K = 100
T = 1
r = 0

underlying_1d = np.linspace(100,120,25)
sigma_1d     = np.linspace(0.05,0.3,50)

underlying, sigma = np.meshgrid(underlying_1d, sigma_1d)

Vanna_df = pandas.DataFrame(
    Vanna_(underlying, K, T, r, sigma),
    columns=underlying_1d,
    index=sigma_1d
    )
Vanna_df.index.name  = 'volatility'
Vanna_df.columns.name = 'Strike'
Vanna_df.iloc[:10,:10]
```

Now **a contourplot**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
        z=Vanna_df.values,
        x=underlying_1d,
        y=sigma_1d
    ))
fig.update_layout(title='Vanna', autosize=False, 
                  xaxis_title='volatility', yaxis_title='strike',
                  width=700, height=500)
fig.show()
```

[image: contour plot]

and your **surface plot**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Surface(
        z=Vanna_df.values,
        x=underlying_1d,
        y=sigma_1d
    ))
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=True,
                                  highlightcolor="limegreen", project_z=True))

fig.update_layout(title='Vanna', autosize=False,
                  width=700, height=500)
fig.show()
```

[image: surface]

(Note: it is not my habit to post code on `quant.stackexchange` but I am training myself to use `Plotly` nowadays...)